# How to show row number in angular datatable columns

Tags: angular-datatables

I'm new in angular and want to display list of results in angular datatables. I have a problem to display a row number in one of the column  in my datatables. Currently when i click on page 2, the row number will start again at 1. Supposedly, it should start at 11 as the results is 10 records per page). Here is my code

```
 this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      destroy: true,
      pageLength: 10,
      searching: false,
      lengthChange: false,
      rowCallback: function (row, data, displayIndex, ) {
        $('td:eq(1)', row).html('' + displayIndex+1);
        return row;
      },
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve it. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it for a simple cursor pagination. Maybe it will be useful.

```js
export function fillNumber({ start, end }: fillNumberArgs): number[] {
    const numbers: number[] = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}

export type fillNumberArgs = {
    start: number;
    end: number;
};


this.numbers = this.fillNumber({
    start: this.filter.skip + 1,
    end: this.filter.skip + this.filter.take,
});
```